# I'd like to be able to view only questions of a tag in my Interesting Tags" section

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be a great feature to be able to view Questions by "Interested"... This option would only show questions matching the tags you have in your "Interesting Tags" section on the right of the page.  Sometimes I want to filter out everything other than those tags, instead of just selecting *one*.

Does this feature already exist?

Comment: Thanks.  But it would be a lot easier to be able to just press a button :)  I have a ton of tags in my list :)  I am going to do the bookmark thing though..  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Combine them with `+OR+` and bookmark the URL.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash+OR+flex

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ninja search options:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

> [tag1] [tag2]